# Activate API (Fusion Tables API) in copy of spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-fusion-tables

In a spreadsheet I have a script that allows to insert the spreadsheet data into a fusion table.
I activated the API (Fusion Tables API), and this script works properly.

When I make a copy of the spreadsheet, I get the message:
Access Not Configured. The API (Fusion Tables API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.

How to do : API (Fusion Tables API) is enabled automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. There is no programmatic method to enable advanced services or enable the API from the Google developers console. 
  What you can do is remake your script into an Add-on. You can use advanced services from an Add-on.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/